# Dealing with Multi-Level Hashes in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm requesting data from an API that returns a multi-level hash in a rails app. I need to access information at different points in the API response, so I have code like this in my view:

```
<%= @api_response["Hash 1"]["Hash 2"]["Hash 3"]["value"] %>
```

In the same view file I might have something like:

```
<%= @api_response["Hash 1"]["value"] %>
```

Is this an acceptable way to deal with an large hash from an API response? Or is there a better way this could be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have a look at [recursive-open-struct gem](https://github.com/aetherknight/recursive-open-struct), it allows to access hash just like methods and also much cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

Since Ruby 2.3.0, Ruby now natively supports this with [`Hash#dig`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-dig). 
From the documentation:

```
h = { foo: {bar: {baz: 1}}}

h.dig(:foo, :bar, :baz)           #=> 1
h.dig(:foo, :zot, :xyz)           #=> nil

g = { foo: [10, 11, 12] }
g.dig(:foo, 1)                    #=> 11
```

---

Another, more convenient example usage:

```
hpath = %i[foo bar baz]
h.dig(*hpath)                     #=> 1
```